# Is there an iOS API which can be called to make an app recompile itself while loaded in XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Essentially, something like [UIApplication pressPlayButtonInXCode]. It is for deeper integration into our in-house IDE.

Comment: What you want may not be possible. You could look into linraries like this one - https://github.com/DyCI/dyci-main , and try to either incorporate them into your project or base on their ideas to come with your own solution.

Comment: You could use the command line tools. Start with `xcodebuild`.